# How can I change the encoding/charset of a string on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding

I'm getting some text from a div, like this:

```
var scriptContent = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerHTML;
```

But if the text contains some like "X is < than Y" the scriptContent var will contain "X is **&lt** than Y". I really need to get exactly the same string I am seeing in the browser, that is "X is < than Y".

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML

*Note: If a , , or  node has a child text node that includes the characters (&), (<), or (>), innerHTML returns these characters as &amp, &lt and &gt respectively. **Use Node.textContent to get a correct copy of these text nodes' contents.***

```
document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].textContent;
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent

Answer (score 1):

Use `textContent` property instead of `innerHTML`:

```
var pre = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0],
    scriptContent = pre.textContent || pre.innerText;
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KNGXs/). An alternative `innerText` is for IE<9.